# How do I pull individual columns in Crosstab from pandas library in python?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have the following code:

```
def readcsv():

    csv_data = read_csv(file,usecols=[0,1,24,25,26],parse_dates=[0],dtype=object)
    csv_data1 = csv_data.values

    return csv_data1

def main():
    d = readcsv()
    df = DataFrame(d)
    d1=df[1]
    d0=df[0]
    d2=df[2]
    d3=df[3]
    d4=df[4]


    ct = pd.crosstab(d0,[d2,d1,d3],rownames=['Date'],colnames=['RigStat','Prov','Obj'], margins=False)
```

At this step, the result is a table:

```
RigStat     DRILL                                              ...   MIR       \
Prov           AB                                           BC ...    MB   SK   
Obj           BIT  BRN  CBM  GAS  NON  OIL  SVC  WST  WTR  NON ...   OIL  GAS     
Date                                                           ...              
2006-08-22     15    1   20  235    0   63    4    0    0    0 ...     1    4   
2006-08-29     17    1   24  242    0   61    5    0    1    0 ...     0    5     
2006-09-06     14    0   22  210    0   50    4    0    0    0 ...     1    4     
2006-09-12     13    0   21  230    0   60    4    0    0    0 ...     0    3     
2006-09-19     14    0    7  155    0   35    2    1    1    1 ...     2    2
```

Now, I want to be able to create a new table, only including those columns under "Drill", how can I do this? I haven't even been able to pull an individual column here because the `Dataframe` is indexed by Date.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newdf = ct['DRILL']` should do it.

Alternatively you can take a cross-section: `newdf = ct.xs('DRILL', level='RigStat', axis=1)`

Comment: I tried both methods and still am getting an error. For the first one, the output gives me: KeyError: 'Drill'. For the second solution the output gives me:  KeyError: 'Drill'. Not sure what to do here, the values below are frequencies.

Comment: sorry `'Drill'` should be `'DRILL'` (all caps) @carevans88

Comment: Dude thank you very much for your help. I had been messing around with this for a couple days and didn't realize that the call was case sensitive. Once again, your help was very much appreciated. This was my first post on here and I am really impressed by the community they have going here!